# What firewall ports need to be open to allow access to external git repositories?

Tags: firewall, port, git

What firewall port(s) need to be open to allow access to external git repositories?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Specifically TCP 9418, no need for UDP.

[Reference](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol).

Answer (score 104):

It depends on the repository.

The native git transport uses TCP port 9418. However, git can also run over ssh (often used for pushing), http, https, and less often others.

You can look at the repository URL to find out which port it uses. Notice that many public repositories have several alternate URLs; for instance, the kernel.org repositories have `git://`, `http://`, and `https://` URLs.

The common URL schemes for git repositories are:

- `ssh://` - default port 22
- `git://` - default port 9418
- `http://` - default port 80
- `https://` - default port 443

If the URL does not have a scheme, it it using ssh with a slightly different syntax.

See the [git fetch manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html#URLS) for more details on the available URL schemes.

Comment: Thank you for the additional ports and justification for each. This is a more complete answer to the question.

Answer (score 6):

Git uses port 9418. You can view connections using that port with

`netstat -ntpl|grep -i 9418`

Open 9418 and your traffic will pass through the firewall.

Comment: Got `The term 'grep' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included` I guess it is not linux

Comment: @tribbloid That's a PowerShell error.. The equivalent for `grep` there is `Select-String`.

Answer (score 3):

I've also found that the outbound SSH port 22 might need to be open as well as port 9418 for Git (both TCP). Depends on your setup though!

Comment: csf config for GIT 
`TCP_IN = "9418"
TCP_OUT = "9418,22"`