# Not able to connect to GitHub though the Firewall

Tags: firewall, github, fortigate

We have Fortigate Firewall install on the network, What port I should open to connect to the GitHub repository using the https:// protocol.

I found a similar [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/189070/what-firewall-ports-need-to-be-open-to-allow-access-to-external-git-repositories) , And allowed the port suggested but still not able to push, pull etc. showing below message.

```
Cannot connect to the remote repository at https://xxxx@github.com/xxxxxx/Reporsitory.git
```

Is there any specific setting in Fortigate?

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS uses TCP port 443 -- you will need to open that port.

Also, are you sure that you haven't misspelled `Reporsitory.git` in your request?